# Where is github authentication token stored on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, github

If I run a command similar to the following on a private repository:

```bsh
git ls-remote https://github.com/org/repo.git
```

I'm getting this following prompt.

[image]

I'm using https://gitforwindows.org and looking at the Process Explorer, it appears that the executable that produces this window is `\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager.exe` relative to Git for Windows installation folder.

When I put in my credentials, I'm getting an email from Github, saying that a new authentication token is created.

Where is this token stored on my PC? When I repeat the command above I'm no longer getting the prompt - as long as I do not revoke the token on the github web site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, Git will use the [Windows Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0) for storing and retrieving Git credentials via Github for Windows desktop.

> Credential Manager lets you view and delete your saved credentials for signing in to websites, connected applications, and networks.
>
> To open Credential Manager, type credential manager in the search box on the taskbar and select **Credential Manager Control** panel.
> Select **Web Credentials** or **Windows Credentials** to access the credentials you want to manage.

You will find the `GitHub - https://api.github.com/{username}` entry on the **Windows Credentials** tab.

Answer (score 8):

Mike Mackintosh is right. Here is how you can access the token.

```bsh
Install-Module CredentialManager -Scope AllUsers -Force
```

Change flags on the above command to your liking. Then:

```bsh
Get-StoredCredential -AsCredentialObject | %{$_} `
  | ?{ $_.targetName -like "*github.com*"} `
  | sort LastWritten `
  | select LastWritten,Targetname,Password
```

This will get you the list of tokens you may have created. Use `Get-Command -Module CredentialManager` to list all avialble commands on the module, you can use to manipulate the credentials store.

Comment: Nice assist, Go team!

Comment: I think you might have saved my github account. Thank you very much

Comment: @Caponte, how did you recover your account with the personal token, I got mine but I can't use it with GH cli, unfortunately, wondering if there's a way to sign in with that in github.com

Comment: @DanielLopes I don't remember the exact process, but I went thought the account recovery process on GitHub.com and eventually reached the point where different proofs of ownership or auth methods were accepted, 2FA, Recovery Codes, the token, etc. I used the token that I had on my Windows machine and it worked. However, before that I tried to use the one in my GUI app, and it didn't because the permissions were not enough.