Git not caching credentials
I am having a peculiar issue with git where whenever I commit the code to git (I use SourceTree), I am getting the below error.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
When this happens if I go to Credentials Manager->Windows Credentials, I can see lot of entries related to git there. Something like this:
git:https:://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo/xxx
git:https:://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo/xxx
git:https:://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo/xxx
git:https:://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo/xxx
git:https:://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo/xxx

I then have to delete them one after the other. After that I am able to commit the changes via SourceTree successfully. It looks like something messed up with git configuration but I am unable to figure out.
I have set the below in my ".gitconfig.config" file
[http]
  sslVerify = false
  sslcainfo = C:/Users/xxx/mymwg.cer
[https]
  sslcainfo = C:/Users/xxx/mymwg.cer
[credential]
  helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper --profile shareddev01 $@
  usehttppath = true

I also tried running the below from command line but no luck.
git config --global http.sslVerify false

I am unable to spot the reason for this behavior. Any help is much appreciated.

possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552941/github-tls-certificate-verification-has-been-disabled-on-windows
